# Does iostream occupy stack space?

Tags: c++, memory, stream, stack, iostream

Suppose the code below,

```
int* foo(){
  int a=5;
  return &a;
}
int main(){
  int* b=foo();
  std::cout<<*b<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding of this program is that the life time of a is only in foo. After foo() is finished, a should not be valid. But since no function overwrites that chunk of stack, it still prints 5. Please correct me if this is wrong.

If the above is right, my question is, I called std::cout<<, the output stream; I actually called something, will it take some space on the stack? Or how exactly it works in memory. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Your question is about `a`, not the `iostream.`

Comment: The compiler may not even bother to return `&a` as it's unusuable anyway. This may appear to be counter-intuitive. After all, you did write it. But many C++ compilers _optimize_ the resulting binaries by removing statements that do not contribute to the correct result. Such optimizers aren't magic, they need rules to determine which statements are safe to remove. And those rules can have rather unexpected results on broken programs like this.

Answer (score 2):

"But since no function overwrites that chunk of stack". You don't know that for sure: there's nothing in the C++ standard that suggests that. I could build a standards-compliant compiler that overwrites that chunk of the stack. Perhaps my implementation of `std::cout` would do that.

Formally the behaviour of your program is *undefined*. You can't say any more.